# Minimum supported python version of boto-2.38.0

Tags: python, django

Does any one know what is the minimum supported python version of boto-2.38.0?

Answer (score 2):

From [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/boto/2.38.0) [Bold and Italic added by me]

> Boto is developed mainly using **Python 2.6.6** and **Python 2.7.3** on Mac
>   OSX and Ubuntu Maverick. It is known to work on other Linux
>   distributions and on Windows. Most of Boto requires no additional
>   libraries or packages other than those that are distributed with
>   Python. *Efforts are made to keep boto compatible with Python 2.5.x but
>   no guarantees are made.*

And concerning Python 3.x (same source)

> Work is under way to support Python 3.3+ in the same codebase

Answer (score 0):

This page: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/boto/2.38.0

leads me to believe Python 2.6.